# How to see methods from other class

Tags: java, class

I got a class where I made multiple methods, but I want to put some of them in another class, since they do other things. How can I have my first class still use my methods?

`Class A` had 15 `private static methods`(they are static since they just return values and I don't need to define an object)

I created `Class B` in the same package and when moving 5 methods in it, the `main function from A` will not detect them when used.

Comment: Are they still static? If so, just use ClassB.methodName(). If not, then create an instance of ClassB and use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the visibility. `private` means only the wrapping class can see these methods.

Set the visibility to default (if both classes are in the same package) or `public` if they're in different packages.

For example, classes A and B are in same package:

```
// A.java
public class A {
    static void oneMethod();
}

// B.java
public class B {
    private static void anotherMethod() {
        A.oneMethod();
    }
}
```

or in different packages:

```
// A.java
public class A {
    public static void oneMethod();
}

// B.java
public class B {
    private static void anotherMethod() {
        A.oneMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I did afterwards and it gives me "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type". Fairly certain that it should work. I did think that private means for other packages.

Comment: I think that error *"Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym"* type has nothing to do with your question or this answer, the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: That's what happened after I changed all my methods to public.

Comment: You're obviously doing something else than changing the methods visibility. You probably have a repeated visibility modifier (e.g. `public private`). Sorry I can't guess any further without the code or at least the line that throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've defined the methods as `private`. You should define them as `package protected` (remove the 'private' part), or `public` (replace private with public).

Having said that: having a class with 15 private static methods is so uncommon that I'd add the label 'bad practice' to it. Can you share your code, so that it's more clear what these methods are doing? Unless you are creating a utility class, say StringUtils, I'm pretty sure there's a small chance you need any static methods at all.

Comment: Code has 500 lines, can't share it. I made all methods private, but it gives me an error.Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type